# Parametrize 3D Model

Tags: opengl, 3d, texture-mapping, 3d-model

I am working with a group on developing an application that captures 2D image of a human and convert it into 3D model. We have used stasm library to do ASM http://www.milbo.org/stasm-files/stasm4.pdf and we are on a limited time plan we need to finish this project by the end of November, so learning what we are trying to do by OpenGL is not our best idea because it has a very advanced learning curve

What we are trying to do is to parametrize the features of the face according to that data from stasm, so we have this model that we classified his nose as an object on blender so  the obj file where we added comments above the keypoints in the nose

then we developed a parser

```
int str2num(string s){

    if (s.length() > 2){
        string str= s.substr((s.length()-2), s.find(' '));
        int value = (int)atof(str.c_str());
        return value;
    }
    else
        return 0;

}


void rokko::objToTxt(const string aInFilename,const string aOutFilename,bool aVerbose)
{
    if(aVerbose) cout << "Loading OBJ file <"
                      << aInFilename << ">" << endl;

    // Open file
    ifstream objFile(aInFilename.c_str());

    if(objFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error: could not open file <"
             << aInFilename << ">" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }


    // Extract verts, normals, textures, and faces
    vector<int> verts, norms, textures;
    vector<int> faces;
    // map<int,int> faceHash;

    vector<int> finalVerts, finalNorms, finalTextures;
    vector<int> finalFaces;

    string line;
    int line_size=0;
    int hashIndex = 0;

    if(aVerbose) cout << "Extracting values from file" << endl;

    // Visit each line of the obj file
    while(getline(objFile, line))
    {
        // Extract vertex
        // Line starts with v[space]...
        if(line[0] == 'v' && line[1] == ' ')
        {
            string lineVals = line.substr(2);
            float val;

            string val0 = lineVals.substr(0, lineVals.find(' '));
            val = (float)atof(val0.c_str());
            verts.push_back(val);
            line_size = val0.size();
            string val1 = lineVals.substr(val0.length() + 1,
                                          lineVals.find(' '));
            val = (float)atof(val1.c_str());
            verts.push_back(val);


            string val2 = lineVals.substr(lineVals.find_last_of(' ') + 1);
            val = (float)atof(val2.c_str());
            verts.push_back(val);
        }


        // Extract textures
        // Line starts with vt[space]...
        else if(line[0] == 'v' && line[1] == 't' && line[2] == ' ')
        {
            string lineVals = line.substr(3);
            float val;

            string val0 = lineVals.substr(0, lineVals.find(' '));
            val = (float)atof(val0.c_str());
            textures.push_back(val);

            string val1 = lineVals.substr(val0.length() + 1,
                                          lineVals.find(' '));
            val = (float)atof(val1.c_str());
            textures.push_back(val);
        }


        // Extract normals
        // Line starts with vn[space]...

        else if(line[0] == 'v' && line[1] == 'n' && line[2] == ' ')
        {
            string lineVals = line.substr(3);
            float val;

            string val0 = lineVals.substr(0, lineVals.find(' '));
            val = (float)atof(val0.c_str());
            norms.push_back(val);

            string val1 = lineVals.substr(val0.length() + 1,
                                          lineVals.find(' '));
            val = (float)atof(val1.c_str());
            norms.push_back(val);

            string val2 = lineVals.substr(lineVals.find_last_of(' ') + 1);
            val = (float)atof(val2.c_str());
            norms.push_back(val);
        }


    }

    for (int i=0; i<verts.size();i++){
        cout << "verts " << i << ": " << verts[i] << endl;}

    for (int i=0; i<verts.size();i++)
    {

        verts[i] = i * 2;
        cout << "verts_new " << i << ": " << verts[i] << endl;}



    // Parametrizing the nose part



    ifstream model ("test.obj");
    ofstream out ("out.obj");


    int test = 1;

    string str;
    string line1, line2,line3;
    int replace_size = (line_size *3) + 2;

    string lineV;
    float val_x, val_y, val_z;
    string val0, val1, val2;

    while(!model.eof())
    {


        getline(model,line1);

        out<<line1<<endl;

        while(line1 =="o N")
        {
            getline(model,line2);


            if (line2 =="o H"){

                line1 = "o H";
                out<<line2<<endl;
            }
            else
            {

                string compare = line2.substr(0, line2.find(' '));

                switch(str2num(compare)){



                case 48: // "#nose_48

                    getline(model,line3);

                    lineV = line3.substr(2);


                    val0 = lineV.substr(0, lineV.find(' '));
                    val_x = (float)atof(val0.c_str());


                    line_size = val0.size();

                    val1 = lineV.substr(val0.length() + 1,lineV.find(' '));
                    val_y= (float)atof(val1.c_str());


                    val2 = lineV.substr(lineV.find_last_of(' ') + 1);
                    val_z= (float)atof(val2.c_str());

                    out<<"v "<<val_x+0.1<<" "<<val_y<<" "<<val_z<<endl;

                    break;

                case 49: // "#nose_49

                    getline(model,line3);

                    lineV = line3.substr(2);


                    val0 = lineV.substr(0, lineV.find(' '));
                    val_x = (float)atof(val0.c_str());


                    line_size = val0.size();

                    val1 = lineV.substr(val0.length() + 1,lineV.find(' '));
                    val_y= (float)atof(val1.c_str());


                    val2 = lineV.substr(lineV.find_last_of(' ') + 1);
                    val_z= (float)atof(val2.c_str());

                    out<<"v "<<val_x<<" "<<val_y<<" "<<val_z<<endl;


                    break;

                case 50: // "#nose_50

                    getline(model,line3);

                    lineV = line3.substr(2);


                    val0 = lineV.substr(0, lineV.find(' '));
                    val_x = (float)atof(val0.c_str());


                    line_size = val0.size();

                    val1 = lineV.substr(val0.length() + 1,lineV.find(' '));
                    val_y= (float)atof(val1.c_str());


                    val2 = lineV.substr(lineV.find_last_of(' ') + 1);
                    val_z= (float)atof(val2.c_str());

                    out<<"v "<<val_x-0.1<<" "<<val_y<<" "<<val_z<<endl;


                    break;

                case 51: // "#nose_51

                    getline(model,line3);

                    lineV = line3.substr(2);


                    val0 = lineV.substr(0, lineV.find(' '));
                    val_x = (float)atof(val0.c_str());


                    line_size = val0.size();

                    val1 = lineV.substr(val0.length() + 1,lineV.find(' '));
                    val_y= (float)atof(val1.c_str());


                    val2 = lineV.substr(lineV.find_last_of(' ') + 1);
                    val_z= (float)atof(val2.c_str());

                    out<<"v "<<val_x<<" "<<val_y-0.1<<" "<<val_z<<endl;



                    break;

                case 52: // "#nose_52


                    getline(model,line3);

                    lineV = line3.substr(2);


                    val0 = lineV.substr(0, lineV.find(' '));
                    val_x = (float)atof(val0.c_str());


                    line_size = val0.size();

                    val1 = lineV.substr(val0.length() + 1,lineV.find(' '));
                    val_y= (float)atof(val1.c_str());


                    val2 = lineV.substr(lineV.find_last_of(' ') + 1);
                    val_z= (float)atof(val2.c_str());

                    out<<"v "<<val_x<<" "<<val_y<<" "<<val_z<<endl;



                    break;

                case 53: // "#nose_53


                    getline(model,line3);

                    lineV = line3.substr(2);


                    val0 = lineV.substr(0, lineV.find(' '));
                    val_x = (float)atof(val0.c_str());


                    line_size = val0.size();

                    val1 = lineV.substr(val0.length() + 1,lineV.find(' '));
                    val_y= (float)atof(val1.c_str());


                    val2 = lineV.substr(lineV.find_last_of(' ') + 1);
                    val_z= (float)atof(val2.c_str());

                    out<<"v "<<val_x<<" "<<val_y-0.1<<" "<<val_z<<endl;



                    break;

                case 54: // "#nose_54

                    getline(model,line3);

                    lineV = line3.substr(2);


                    val0 = lineV.substr(0, lineV.find(' '));
                    val_x = (float)atof(val0.c_str());


                    line_size = val0.size();

                    val1 = lineV.substr(val0.length() + 1,lineV.find(' '));
                    val_y= (float)atof(val1.c_str());


                    val2 = lineV.substr(lineV.find_last_of(' ') + 1);
                    val_z= (float)atof(val2.c_str());

                    out<<"v "<<val_x+0.1<<" "<<val_y<<" "<<val_z<<endl;



                    break;



                case 55: // "#nose_55

                    getline(model,line3);

                    lineV = line3.substr(2);


                    val0 = lineV.substr(0, lineV.find(' '));
                    val_x = (float)atof(val0.c_str());


                    line_size = val0.size();

                    val1 = lineV.substr(val0.length() + 1,lineV.find(' '));
                    val_y= (float)atof(val1.c_str());


                    val2 = lineV.substr(lineV.find_last_of(' ') + 1);
                    val_z= (float)atof(val2.c_str());

                    out<<"v "<<val_x+0.1<<" "<<val_y<<" "<<val_z<<endl;



                    break;



                case 56: // "#nose_56

                    getline(model,line3);

                    lineV = line3.substr(2);


                    val0 = lineV.substr(0, lineV.find(' '));
                    val_x = (float)atof(val0.c_str());


                    line_size = val0.size();

                    val1 = lineV.substr(val0.length() + 1,lineV.find(' '));
                    val_y= (float)atof(val1.c_str());


                    val2 = lineV.substr(lineV.find_last_of(' ') + 1);
                    val_z= (float)atof(val2.c_str());

                    out<<"v "<<val_x<<" "<<val_y-0.2<<" "<<val_z<<endl;



                    break;


                case 57: // "#nose_57

                    getline(model,line3);

                    lineV = line3.substr(2);


                    val0 = lineV.substr(0, lineV.find(' '));
                    val_x = (float)atof(val0.c_str());


                    line_size = val0.size();

                    val1 = lineV.substr(val0.length() + 1,lineV.find(' '));
                    val_y= (float)atof(val1.c_str());


                    val2 = lineV.substr(lineV.find_last_of(' ') + 1);
                    val_z= (float)atof(val2.c_str());

                    out<<"v "<<val_x-0.1<<" "<<val_y<<" "<<val_z<<endl;



                    break;


                case 58: // "#nose_58

                    getline(model,line3);

                    lineV = line3.substr(2);


                    val0 = lineV.substr(0, lineV.find(' '));
                    val_x = (float)atof(val0.c_str());


                    line_size = val0.size();

                    val1 = lineV.substr(val0.length() + 1,lineV.find(' '));
                    val_y= (float)atof(val1.c_str());


                    val2 = lineV.substr(lineV.find_last_of(' ') + 1);
                    val_z= (float)atof(val2.c_str());

                    out<<"v "<<val_x-0.1<<" "<<val_y<<" "<<val_z<<endl;



                    break;


                    //

                default:

                    out<<line2<<endl;



                    break;
                }

            }



        }


    }

    model.close();
    out.close(); 

}
```

and we can't seem to get it right

Any help of an alternative approach without using libraries that are hard to learn.

Comment: you don't do anything with the faces and you don't parse the `f` lines

Comment: because I an changing in the vertices not the faces ? Why would I change the faces

Comment: @ratchetfreak Am I suppose to change in the faces ? Help please